# Rollover fade on fluid image

Tags: responsive-design, fluid-layout, rollover-effect

I'm creating a responsive site with a gallery composed of fluids images . For this, I must use css **img {max-width: 100%;}**.  I also want a fade effect on hover.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

So far, all the solutions I've tried, does'nt work with css **img {max-width: 100%;}**

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Define image width also along with its max-width. And it must be in pixels or em's. 
You don't need to keep max-width or min-width in %'s. 
Browser renders from its original width or height value. As

This is for example.

```
img{
    width:50%;
    height:30%;
    max-width:300px;
    min-height:100px;
    }
```

And every images'll be flexible with viewport.

Comment: Thanks, Camille. If you really find this answer useful, then please recommend it. I appreciate for your moving forward.